# On extensions and lifts

Tags: category-theory

I'm about 70 pages into Lawvere & Schanuel's book Conceptual Mathematics and came across a question while solving an exercise, which at first seemed trivial but after toying around with it some more left me rather confused. I shall rephrase and expand upon the question as follows:

Throughout, let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category with a terminal object $\textbf{1}$.

Let $X\stackrel{\tilde{f}}{\longrightarrow}Y$ be a morphism in $\mathscr{C}$ such that $\tilde{f}\circ g=f$ for some morphisms $Z\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}Y$ and $Z\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}X$, i.e. $\tilde{f}$ is an extension of $f$ along $g$. It follows immediately that for any pair $\textbf{1}\stackrel{z_1, z_2}{\rightrightarrows}Z$ of global elements, one has the implication:

$$g(z_1)=g(z_2) \implies f(z_1)=f(z_2)$$

My question being, is the converse statement true? And if not, under what additional assumptions will it be true? In other words, if two morphisms $f$ and $g$ satisfy the above implication, must there necessarily exist an extension of $f$ along $g$? (Naturally every monic $g$ will trivially satisfy the implication.)

I figured I would simply construct a counterexample and disprove the claim, however all of the examples I managed to conjure up so far have only hinted towards the affirmative. Though I suspect there is something quite straightforward I ought to have overlooked.

An analogous question arises when examining the dual notion of a $\textit{lift}$, where the situation is practically the same as above. I will not describe it here, as I suspect the answer to the former will reveal the answer to the latter. Any hints are appreciated.

EDIT: I apologize for the confusion. I did not mean to imply that I was seeking the converse implication, but rather I am assuming the original implication and seeking to construct an extension.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but wouldn't the converse be false in the category of sets when $Y$ is a one-element set, and $g$ is a bijection between two larger sets?

Comment: @Vickie In that case, the extension is the unique constant morphism into the terminal object. Making $g$ an isomorphism doesn't really impact much, except that the implication is trivially satisfied.

Comment: I don't understand the question: if $g$ is a monic but $Y$ isn't injective with respect to $g$, i.e. $\hom(g,Y)$ is not an epimorphism, the implication holds, but not all liftings exist.

Comment: @Fosco I don't understand the comment: Aren't you by definition assuming that there isn't an extension/lifting?

Comment: I am just saying that there is plenty of situations where the extension does not exist, even if $g$ is monic, and so the implication you want to hold, indeed holds. General topology will provide many counterexamples, and extension problems like the one in Tietze's theorem; but also smaller ones, like the one in the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the converse implication:

Given $f:Z\rightarrow Y, g:Z\rightarrow X$ and $\widetilde{f}:X \rightarrow Y$ with $f=\widetilde{f}g$ and global points $z_1,z_2:1\rightarrow Z$ then clearly
$$gz_1 = gz_2 \Rightarrow fz_1 = \widetilde{f}gz_1 = \widetilde{f}gz_2 = fz_2$$
The converse does not hold in general, for example in the case $\mathscr{C}=\mathsf{Set}$ with $Z=X=\{0,1\}, Y=\{*\},f,\widetilde{f}$ constant and $g=\operatorname{id}$. However if $\widetilde{f}$ is monic we obtain
$$fz_1 = fz_2 \Leftrightarrow \widetilde{f}gz_1 = \widetilde{f}gz_2 \Rightarrow gz_1 = gz_2$$

Regarding the existence of an extension:

Take $\mathscr{C}=\mathsf{Top}$ with $Z=Y=\{0,1\}_\text{disc}, X =\{0,1\}_\text{chaot}$ and $f,g=\operatorname{id}$ on underlying sets. Then obviously the implication holds, but there cannot be an extension $\widetilde{f}:X=\{0,1\}_\text{chaot} \rightarrow Y=\{0,1\}_\text{disc}$ by continuity reasons.

Comment: Fantastically simple counterexample! I am still wondering whether an extension must always exist in $\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: Thanks. I think there should be a (non-unique) extension, since in $\mathsf{Set}$ there are no real obstructions for defining maps. This is why I deferred to $\mathsf{Top}$ for the counterexample...